# Why increment not saves in conditional operator?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, increment

I wonder why in this code counter is not saving after it is incremented?
I mean now the behavior  is the same as if I used   `if (counter+1 % 2)`. But `++` operator supposed to permanently increment the variable.

```js
let counter=0;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(counter,'every')
    if (counter++ % 2) console.log(counter,'odd');
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not saving? The counter is increasing.

Comment: You're testing the old value with `%`, not the incremented value.

Comment: use `++counter` prefix not postfix.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to have `++` in front of `counter`

```js
let counter=0;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(counter,'every')
    if (++counter % 2) console.log(counter,'odd');
}
```

Comment: See also: [Arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Examples_7)

Answer (score -1):

If you use the ++ operator after the variable it will only increment after the line code is executed, if you put it behind the variable it will increment before the line code.